# how to search an array full of objects based on a key and return a specific object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array of objects as :

```
    [{
    "businessunit": [{
        "Area": [{
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 11"
                },
                "name": "Field 1"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 12"
                },
                "name": "Field 2"
            }],
            "name": "Archer"
        }, {
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 13"
                },
                "name": "Field 3"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 14"
                },
                "name": "Field 4"
            }],
            "name": "Anderson"
        }],
        "name": "North America"
    }, {
        "Area": [{
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 15"
                },
                "name": "Field 5"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 16"
                },
                "name": "Field 6"
            }],
            "name": "ArcherSouth"
        }, {
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 17"
                },
                "name": "Field 7"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 18"
                },
                "name": "Field 8"
            }],
            "name": "AndersonSouth"
        }],
        "name": "South America"
    }],
    "name": "XYZ Oil Co"
}, {
    "businessunit": [{
        "Area": [{
            "Asset": {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 19"
                },
                "name": "Field 9"
            },
            "name": "Archer"
        }, {
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 110"
                },
                "name": "Field 10"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 120"
                },
                "name": "Field 20"
            }],
            "name": "Anderson"
        }],
        "name": "North America"
    }, {
        "Area": {
            "Asset": [{
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 130"
                },
                "name": "Field 30"
            }, {
                "Wells": {
                    "Well": "Well 140"
                },
                "name": "Field 40"
            }],
            "name": "AndersonSouth"
        },
        "name": "South America"
    }],
    "name": "ABC Oil Co"
}];
```

I want to search based on a key supplied and return a specific object containing that key.

For example : if I pass `key = "North America"`, I will get:

```
{
    "Area": [{
        "Asset": [{
            "Wells": {
                "Well": "Well 11"
            },
            "name": "Field 1"
        }, {
            "Wells": {
                "Well": "Well 12"
            },
            "name": "Field 2"
        }],
        "name": "Archer"
    }, {
        "Asset": [{
            "Wells": {
                "Well": "Well 13"
            },
            "name": "Field 3"
        }, {
            "Wells": {
                "Well": "Well 14"
            },
            "name": "Field 4"
        }],
        "name": "Anderson"
    }],
    "name": "North America"
}
```

I tried this

```
function search(nameKey, myArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
                    return myArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
```

But since my array of object again contain more array of objects . It was not helpful.

Comment: Can you format your question? And why didn't your attempt work again?

Comment: The text of your question is currently *very* difficult to read. Perhaps you could pick a simpler example, and add code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

use a filter:

`var results = $filter('filter')(myArray, { 'name': nameKey }, true)`